# php header content-type image/jpeg security question

Tags: php, security, types

Hi I was wondering if the following would pose any threats ? The url is take from the browser checks if its a picture and output it otherwise display "image does not exist".
I haven't done the if statement yet. But should i put anymore header(); settings before outputting or any other suggestions that could make it a bit more secure if I have missed any.

```
header('content-type: image/jpeg');
$file = urlencode('http://domain.com/images/file.jpg');
ob_start();
require_once($file);
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
echo $out;
```

Comment: So to confirm, the incoming URL is arbitrary? Where and how are you checking whether it is an image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's a huge security risk, as you're asking PHP to interprete a remote file. If a user may pass any URI to your script, he'll be able to make control of your server with ease.

You should use the `cURL` functions or a simple `file_get_contents` (or `fopen`) call, if the URL wrappers are available on your installation.

Comment: do you think i best use `file_get_contents` and remove the `ob_`?

Comment: also do you have any other recommendatiosn to go on `header()` besides the `header('content-type: image/jpeg');` to improve security or anything else

Comment: If the file comes from a remote host, I'd download it to a local file (created using tmpfile()), run finfo_file() on it, in order to detect whether it's really an image and stream it to the client. You can add an additional 'Content-Disposition' header in order to force a download of the image, rather than displaying it. But this may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely shouldn't be using require_once for that.

Use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

```
header('content-type: image/jpeg');
$file = urlencode('http://domain.com/images/file.jpg');
readfile($file);
exit();
```